How the addition of probabilities of drawing balls from a bag (without replacement) works
Looking at a question like Probability of taking balls without replacement from a bag question, with its given answers gives a pretty good idea of how to solve the drawing balls from a bag question. What I am more concerned with, however, is how this works when looking at an individual case vs the whole.
For example, given a bag with $N$ balls, one of which is golden, the probability of drawing that golden ball on any given draw is $1/n$, where $n$ is the number of balls remaining in the bag. Obviously, given how combinatoric probabilities work, we cannot simply add these up as independent events. But why not?
If the probability of drawing the golden ball when $n=10$ is $1/10$, and the probability of drawing the golden ball when $n=1$ is $1$, then why doesn't it work to add up the probabilities as if they were independent? i.e. $$ \sum_{n=1}^{10}\frac{1}{n} = 1/1 + 1/2 + ... 1/10 $$
I know that formula adds up to more than 1 so it can't work, but it also makes sense intuitively. What is it that makes this not work?

The probability of having drawn the golden ball in either the first, second, or third draws when drawing without replacement from a bag with $10$ balls with one of which golden would be $\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{10} = \frac{3}{10}$.  You seem to be overthinking and confusing yourself.

Without replacement, the events of drawing the golden ball on the first, second, third, ..., $N$th attempts are not independent; for example if you draw it on the first attempt, it becomes impossible to draw it again since there is no replacement, but if you do not then it is possible with positive probability.  Instead these events are mutually exclusive and there are a finite number of such events.  So you can add up their probabilities.
When $n$ balls remain, the probability of drawing it on the next attempt  is indeed $\frac1n$, conditional on it not having been drawn in the previous $N-n$ attempts.  The probability of it not being drawn in the first $N-n$ attempts is $1-\frac{N-n}{N}=\frac{n}{N}$ so the initial probability of drawing it on the $n$th attempt is $\frac1n \times \frac{n}{N} =\frac{1}{N}$.
Add these up over $n$ taking the values $1,2,3,\ldots, N$ and you get $\frac{1}{N}+\frac{1}{N}+\frac{1}{N}+\cdots+\frac{1}{N}=1$, as you would hope to see as the probability of drawing the golden ball in exactly one of the $N$ attempts, as you are going to empty the bag and so must draw the golden ball precisely once.

Loosely speaking, if you're adding probabilities for non-exclusive events, you are over counting all the overlap between the events: draw a Venn diagram.
Note that there is a big difference between independent events and mutually exclusive events. The former is when, given events $A$ and $B$, we have $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) = \mathbb{P}(A) \mathbb{P}(B)$. That is, the probability of both occurring is just a matter of using the multiplication rule of counting. The latter, also called disjoint events, is when $A \cap B = \varnothing$. Note that if two events are mutually exclusive, then there is a clear relationship between them, so they are not independent.
Now, formally, speaking, the reason we have the additivity you are talking about when events $E_n$ are mutually exclusive is a measure theoretic consequence. Probability measures are countably additive, so $$\mathbb{P} \left(\bigsqcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n \right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(E_n),$$ and likewise for the finite case of $N$ events (here, the square union just means that we are unioning exclusive events).
We can view your golden ball example as 10 experiments: we have different ten bags, each with $1,2,\dots,10$ balls, and each bag has a single golden ball in it. Then, we can ask the question: what is the probability of picking a golden ball? As you noticed, the answer is not simply adding up the probability of picking the ball from each box with $N$ balls. Why? Let $A$ be the event that you pick the golden ball from the box with $N=1$ balls, and let $B$ be the event that you pick the golden ball from the box with $N=2$ balls. Event $A$ could occur on its own, $B$ could occur on its own, neither could occur, and both could occur. That is, $A \cap B \neq \varnothing$. Hence, our union of all golden ball events is not a disjoint union, so we cannot just add the individual probabilities.

I suggest that you take a closer look at the answer of SlipEternal, in the posted question that you linked to.  In order to use their analysis to answer your (somewhat different) question, you must expand your intuition to acquire a deeper understanding of SlipEternal's answer.
Then, you have to further stretch your intuition to ask yourself what alterations are needed to modify the answer of SlipEternal.  Unfortunately, intuition stretching is not directly taught in probability theory classes, even though it is an indispensable tool (in my opinion).
In fact, intuition is typically stretched merely by repeated exposure to a variety of math problems that use the pertinent concepts.
So, you have no formal way of filling the intuitive gap.

In this problem, in order for the golden ball to be selected on the $~n$-th turn, assuming that $~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}},$ two events have to happen:

The golden ball was not selected on any of the previous $~(n-1)~$ turns.  
The probability of this happening is 
$A = \displaystyle \frac{\binom{N-1}{n-1}}{\binom{N}{n-1}}.$

The golden ball then has to be selected on the $~n$-th turn, when there are $~[ ~N - (n-1) ~]~$ balls left. 
The probability of this happening is 
$B = \displaystyle \frac{1}{N - (n-1)}.$


Then, the overall probability that the golden ball will be selected on the $~n$-th turn is
$$A \times B.$$
